# Cannot start bounty using IE 11

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, internet-explorer

When I click "Start a Bounty" I get the dialog asking me to choose how many points to offer, but when I click `Next` nothing happens (the dialog stays, no points are subtracted, no bounty is added). Clicking `X` or pressing `ESC` will clear the dialog, clicking `cancel` jumps to the top of the page but the popup is still on the screen.

Tested on several SE sites, on both questions posted by me, and questions posted by others.

This is on the latest version of IE, 11.1358.10586.0 on Windows 10. Tested on two machines (a desktop and a MS Surface).

Both are in the same corporate network, so I *suppose* that could be a factor, although I can't imagine that firewall settings would prohibit that one specific action, while I can do everything else on SE sites.

**EDIT**: Still broken. Proof? Had to use Chrome to add a bounty to this question.

Comment: Confirmed as well. Click Cancel doesn't do anything for me. Esc and close do work.

Comment: @rene You're right, cancel doesn't work either. Edited.

Comment: For some reason `$(function(){});` doesn't work anymore in IE11 if the javascript gets loaded in the DOM way after the DOM was ready. If I change it to `setTimeout(function(){},10);` I can proceed to the next page and cancel works as well. But that is more like a hack then a proper fix. I can't find what the root cause is of this and/or when it changed.

Comment: Hidden Feature...

Comment: @rene root cause is IE being IE... borked and weird. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Once I filed a bug for something in a different application; a developer of that commented that "to be fair, there's no standard for this, it's just that IE doesn't do what most of the other browsers do".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

A previously executed `$(function () { ... })` contained a check `if (CSS.supports)` before calling `CSS.supports` directly, but didn't account for the fact that if [`CSS.supports`](https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS.supports) is undefined, `CSS` will also be undefined.

Because this JavaScript error happened inside a ready event callback it broke the `$(function () { ... })` that wires events in the popup.

Comment: Thanks!! Any idea when that build will be available to test?

Comment: Not sure. It's noon on the west coast, so another meta build will probably go out today, but definitely by tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, still within my bounty window, then. I'll test it before awarding :)

Comment: One more question: is that fix going out cross-network? I had the original problem on skeptics.SE.

Comment: The fix is live on Meta now and will be on the rest of the network in the next few minutes.  There's usually not a *big* gap between Meta going live and the rest of the network.  If there is, it's because a dev needs validate something in prod and Meta is a more forgiving test subject.

Comment: Fix confirmed, and bounty awarded! Thanks!

Comment: When did you start using CSS.supports?

Comment: @ShadowWizard 11 days ago.  It looks like it's related to some responsive design work around comments.

Comment: So... comments killed bounties and tag popups. Nice. ;)