# Tag tooltip no longer showing on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer 11, holding the mouse over a tag of a question used to bring up a tooltip with a short description of the tag. Now it only shows "Show questions tagged -tag-".

Where has this useful tooltip gone? Can we have it back in IE please?

Comment: If I'm looking at a tag [foo] that is located _under a question_, and I point my mouse at the [foo] tag, I get the tag description. I only see what you're describing when I point at a tag that is in the right sidebar under "related tags".

Comment: I get it on the questions list page, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c. I also get it on the question detail page.

Comment: Can't reproduce beyond my description on Chrome 64/Win7.

Comment: Also see what you describe under "favorite tags" in right sidebar. However, when I look at right sidebar under "Questions Tagged...", I get the tag description.

Comment: I can repro on IE11/Win10. It looks like that an eventlistener didn't get registered. I can't verify yet if [this is related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306723/cannot-start-bounty-using-ie-11) but I doubt it is a coincidence.

Comment: ***STOP THE PRESSES*** - reproduced in Win7/IE11. I suspect that it's an HTML5 feature that's not properly supported by IE, which is notorious for _not_ conforming to standards. MS has decommitted from IE, and recommends using Windows 10 with Edge.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, that is great. But they can hardly expect me to buy a new machine... But the tag tooltip worked fine. Has something changed on Stack Exchange?

Comment: *has something changed* ... yes, the site will get a responsive layout so a lot of stuff, both html structure as CSS, needs a major overhaul. So far the comment section has been un-tabled but I wouldn't be surprised if that already caused unwanted side-effects. One of which you might experience first hand right now.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome, Edge and Firefox ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hegk2.png)), but I can reproduce it in Internet Explorer ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JXCI.png)).

Comment: Can't reproduce on Edge.

Comment: @Ano well, Edge isn't IE... they finally made something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

This was a slightly different manifestation of the same bug in [Cannot start bounty using IE 11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306723/cannot-start-bounty-using-ie-11).

Right before the code executed that show user messages and wires up user menus, tag preferences, and keyboard shortcuts, we performed a check, `if (CSS.supports)`.  Unfortunately, not only does [`CSS.supports`](https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS.supports) not exist in IE 11, neither does `CSS`, so we got an error checking a property on undefined.

Comment: From iOS to IE. Man, I don't envy you. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Thanks Brian. Glad to get it back :-)

Comment: Solved! The tag tooltip is back. Many thanks!